# Chmod to allow read and write permissions for directory

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I have created directories in root. I am looking for the `chmod` command to allow all users read and write permissions to a specific directory. I have done `chmod 775` for a file but I need this for a directory. This includes permissions on all files and sub directories.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`0775` is rarely correct for a file. The following will add the appropriate desired permissions to the appropriate type, without disturbing other existing permissions:

```
find somedir \( -type d -exec chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rx {} \; -o -type f -exec chmod u+rw,g+rw,o+r {} \; \)
```

See the [man page for find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to help decipher that.

Answer (score 62):

For *all* users to have read and write access, that would be `0777` which is a bit dangerous, especially if you are running a webserver.
Like @unwind said:

`chmod -R 0777 /mydirectory` Will allow all users read and write access to all files and folders within that directory

Depending on your purpose, you may want to read about sticky bits, which allow all users to create new files, but not to delete or edit other files in a directory:

`chmod +t /mydirectory`

Also, in case you didn't know `man chmod` will bring up the manual page for the `chmod` command, which you can search for the text "recursive" by typing `/recursive`

Answer (score 19):

That's not how the Unix protection model works, you can't set permissions recursively. You need to set them on each directory, all the way "down".

Of course you can do the *setting* recursively, but that only means "go through and set these permissions on all files and folders below", which is not how I understand your question.

To do do that, use the [-R option](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) to chmod:

```
$ chmod -R 0755 /my-cool-directory
```

Comment: @unwind -- I mean every file and sub directory of a directory I chmod has read and write permission's for all. Is that what this command does? Thanks

Comment: When I put the -r before the 0755 I get 0755 - no such file or directory.. putting the -r after solves my problem.

Comment: "do do". lol. nice.