# How do I change file permissions on Wordpress on Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions, wordpress

I have reviewed the following link [Chmod to allow read and write permissions for directory](https://superuser.com/questions/126073/chmod-to-allow-read-and-write-permissions-for-directory?rq=1)

However when I run `chmod 755`
I get `chmod: -R: No such file or directory`

This is what I tried to do `chmod 755 -R /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bethel/wp-content`

I would like to know what is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The options/flags should come before the mode you're trying to set. So the correct syntax is:

```
chmod -R 755 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bethel/wp-content
```